# In Vertica, what expression will omit results that contain any numeral?

Tags: sql, vertica

I need to query a Vertica database where addresses are stored and get results where the `varchar` contains no numbers.

For SQL Server someone suggested:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE Column NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%'
```

but this is not working in Vertica, meaning I get returned every address with and without a number in the address1 field. I could do the below, except it is clunky:

```
select * 
from [TABLE_NAME] 
where [FIELD] NOT like '%0%' 
  and [FIELD] NOT like '%1%' 
  and [FIELD] NOT like '%2%' 
  and [FIELD] NOT like '%3%' 
  and [FIELD] NOT like '%4%' 
  and [FIELD] NOT like '%5%' 
  and [FIELD] NOT like '%6%' 
  and [FIELD] NOT like '%7%'
  and [FIELD] NOT like '%8%' 
  and [FIELD] NOT like '%9%';
```

Is there a clean expression that can be used in Vertica that is similar to the statement for SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using SQL Server `LIKE` syntax.  Use regular expressions instead:

```
where not regexp_like(column, '[0-9]')
```

Or, alternatively:

```
where regexp_like(column, '^[^0-9]*$')
```

Answer (score 0):

HP Vertica is a DB engine developed to handle massive amounts of data.
If your project uses Vertica, most probably is handling -or planned to handle- very big amounts of data.

The approach you're taking of not likes, or the alternative with regular expressions, will work but won't scale as good as a native Vertica solution would scale.

Maybe you should look into [projections](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/CREATEPROJECTION.htm) instead -imagine they are materialized views- where you can store in a single bit if the address of that user has numbers or not.